# To set one value in a dropdown list as top one from an array of values : jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist in jquery. I'm filling that dropdown using an array. I want to set one of the values as the first in the list from an array of values.
Say i have 'a','b','c' in an array and i want to set 'b' as the first in the array.

Many thanks in advance..

Comment: `$('select option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and found out the answer:

$("#selectControl").attr('selectedIndex',indexVal);

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
```

where 1 is the index of 'b' inside of your array.

Comment: I tried this and it worked..
$("#selectControl").attr('selectedIndex',indexVal);

Many thanks to all for the quick responses....

Comment: Ah I like that solution even more :)

Comment: $("#selectControl").attr('selectedIndex',indexVal);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set one option as "SELECTED you just have to add it to html like this:

```
<option value='your' SELECTED>Name</option>
```

This will make this option the first of the list or the selected one.
Otherwise the options will follow the order you gave them

```
<option value='your1'>Name1</option>
<option value='your2'>Name1</option>
```

in this case Name1 will appear before Name2

Answer (score 0):

set the property `selected="selected"` in the `<option>` tag for that specific value

Answer (score 0):

You could reorder the array by using a combination of array.splice() and array.concat(). Then do your binding as normal. e.g.

```
var foo = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var bar = foo.splice(1,1); // the first arg is the index of the item to remove
var baz = bar.concat(foo); // baz contains the new array with the 'b' value in the first spot
```

Answer (score 0):

John stickers soloution is good.

If you want to do it with text and not an index, you could do:

```
    //BUILD ARRAY
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

    //BUILD DROPDOWN
    var firstItem = "Mango";
    var buildHTML = "";
    $.each( fruits, function(intIndex, objValue){ 
        if(objValue != firstItem) {
            buildHTML += "<option>"+objValue+"</option>";
        } else {
            buildHTML = "<option>"+objValue+"</option>"+buildHTML;
        }
    });
    $("#dropdownbox").append(buildHTML);
```

And have an empty selectbox

```
<select id="dropdownbox">
</select>
```